# Kotlin initialize array of arrays like python

Tags: kotlin

Why cant i do something like that ?

```
var a=[[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

or at least

```
var a: Array<Array<Int>> = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
```

is it just impossible to do in kotlin?

Comment: Actually that's a List in Python, not an array. So if you want the same in Kotlin you need to use `listOf(listOf(1, 0), listOf(0, 1))` - or  `mutableListOf` in case you want a mutable structure

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin is different language and has different array initialization for example you could use [`arrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html) and also primitive method like [`intArrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/int-array-of.html) for integers

```
arrayOf(intArrayOf(1,0), intArrayOf(0,1))
```